# Mapstruct Internal error in mapping processor: Java.lang.NullPointerExecption at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.Type.hasAccessibleConstructor

Tags: java, mapstruct

```
lombok: 1.18.30
org.mapstruct.version: 1.4.2.Final
JDK 11
Intellij 2023.2.5 Community Eddition
```

I am trying to use Mapstruct to map Some objects. Whenever I try to compile using `mvn -clean install`. It gives the next error

```
Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.common.Type.hasAccessibleConstructor(Type.java:1078)
```

Whenever I click on `Type.java:1078`, it takes me to `Sports.java`

I have two objects: Sports and Football.
Fotball extends from Sports.

```
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @SuperBuilder
    @Jacksonized
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    public class Sports { 
      private String name;
      private String foundation_year;
    }
```

//Fotball

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class Football extends Sports{

}
```

Comment: Find the generated class inside `target/classes/yourpackage` & look if there're a Type class inside. Also, you can post the full class body in the post.

Comment: I have class which name is Type. I renamed, even though it keep showing same error.

Comment: @MohamedMamun can you share ENTITY, DTO and MAPPER ?

Answer (score 0):

just add @NoArgsConstructor annotation.

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Football extends Sports{

}
```